# How does document.cookie affect XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Unlike other headers, [I can't set the Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) using `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader`.

Instead, cookies must be manipulated via `document.cookie`.

Unfortunately, it seems inconstent.

```
document.cookie = 'name=foo';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', url1);
xhr.send();

document.cookie = 'name=bar';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', url2);
xhr.send();
```

In Chrome 47 and IE 10, both requests have `name=bar`. In Firefox 43, the first request has `name=foo` and the second has `name=bar`.

Which of these behaviors complies with HTML5 standards? How can I control the Cookie header for a a request?

---

(Since I know I will be asked about this: [AWS Cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) won't look at any headers except Cookie for serving private content. And hundreds of combined resources don't fit in a policy cookie, so I have to set a different policy cookie for each request. A sad API, but that's why.)

Comment: would a short setTimeout fix chrome's 2nd request?

Comment: Do you really need two requests to the same url?

Comment: @dandavis, I tried. It seems it is a variable quantity. Not sure if it is the length of the DNS lookup or what.

Comment: @hindmost, no. There are to different URLs. I will update.

Comment: Are they cross-domain?

Comment: @hindmost, no, they are not.

Comment: I think making these requests consecutive (2nd after the 1st end) could solve such problem.

Comment: i don't know which is "correct", if any. i think you could chain requests instead of using parrelell as shown, maybe even validating the cookie before send()ing.  or making a fake local request to set cookies with a server between external requests (which would validate it too). lastly, a server-side-proxy to talk to AWS can set cookies reliably from any browser.